# How to prove to a 3rd party that some user logged in?

Tags: authentication

Forgive me any mistakes as I am not very knowledgeable in cryptography.

I would like to prove to any 3rd party that a user, with email $x$, accessed my server/database. Only method I can think of is to request the user to sign some message right after logging in. Problems:

1. The user may not sign the message even though he already logged in.
2. Not all users use digital signature schemes.

Is there any way to solve problems 1 or 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To the question: The whole idea behind login is that it is the for the user to prove that he is who he says he is. Protect access to your server/database by login. As soon as user logged in this shows that he used his password, which confirms that it was really a particular user. Just write this info to the log. Sure, you can use 2-factor / multifactor authentication, but the idea is the same: After user has logged in, you know exactly every subsequent requests to server/database that he has triggered.

Comment: Right. But it only proves it to me that he is who he says he is. I am trying to figure how to prove that the user accessed to a third party.

Comment: You log the actions in the code that the user has triggered. You log database requests. Then show that to the 3rd party. I don't understand why don't you consider this as a solution.

Comment: Because I could make up those logs, couldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

So you say the problem is, that the 3rd party does not trust you.

I don't see a simple solution. Since the 3rd party doesn't trust you, you need a signed confirmation from the user for *each* data package he has received from the server.

Then also the user should not trust you. The user can expect that you want to blame him in accessing some sensitive data that user actually has not requested. That's why the user (client) should sign each request and the server should include this request into its response.

So far it looks complicated, but not yet much complicated.

Now look at the implementation. For a PKI based signature browser needs access to the client public key. From the pure JavaScript you cannot do that. You would need either some browser add-on to make user key / certificate accessible from JavaScript. Or you need a non-browser client (Java, C#, Python, ...) In case of add-on user again should no trust it and needs at least the full source code of this add-on. In case of non-browser application again user needs a full source code of the client application.

Instead of PKI, you can use some other scheme for authentication, e.g. some hardware key like YubiKey or Titan. But still the solution will be not trivial.

A **simpler solution** could be following.

On the server side you log any sensitive operations the user has triggered, any data the user has accessed. When the 3rd party requests any information about user activities, you extract information from the log, send it to the user and ask him to confirm (to sign) this part of the log. User signs it; it doesn't need to be in browser, it can be some offline too). You send this signed log to the 3rd party. User has the right to refuse to sign such a log when you ask him. In such case you  have the right to deny user any further access to your server. This scheme would be much easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, your simple solution is what I had in mind. I guess there is no way to get around using PKI. Problem for that is that it adds friction as most people don't use digital signatures.